# retrive two values in separate textboxes from database using dropdown onchange event jsp without using table index

Tags: javascript, mysql, scriptlet

Following code will show only one value in a text box but what i need is if i select one drop down option it has to display all it's row values in each separate text boxes..retrive two or more values in separate textboxes from database using dropdown onchange event jsp without using table index.

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <%@page import = "java.sql.*" %>
        <%@page import = "java.sql.DriverManager.*" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function populateCustomerId(){
        var selectBox = document.getElementById('selectBox');
         var selectedCustomerId = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
        document.getElementById('customerId').value = selectedCustomerId;

    }</script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Select</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%
    try{   
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ravi","root","root");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = null;
            rs = st.executeQuery("select rid, rname, rmbl from r"); 
    %>
        <select id="selectBox" onchange="populateCustomerId();">
            <%while(rs.next()){ %>

                <option value="<%=rs.getString(2) %>"><%=rs.getString(1) %></option>

            <%} %>
            <%}
        catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } %>

        </select>
        <input id="customerId" type="text" value="" />
        <input id="" type="text" value="" />
        <input id="" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple pass data to your element's data attribute as below

```
<option value="<%=rs.getString(2) %>" data-name="<%=rs.getString(3)%>" data-xyz="value-which-you-want-to-get-in-change-event"><%=rs.getString(1) %></option>
```

Now you can get that value in your change event function

```
function populateCustomerId(){
        var selectBox = document.getElementById('selectBox');
         var selectedCustomerId = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

        var xyz = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-xyz');
        var name = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-name');

        document.getElementById('customerId').value = selectedCustomerId;
        document.getElementById('customerName').value = name;
        document.getElementById('customerXyz').value = xyz;

    }
```

This is just simple example how you can do it.
You can improve it as per your need.

Comment: but its showing all the data in drop down list it is not printing in text boxes when i select the option

Comment: Edit this answer and select it as correct answer. (y)